# LinkedList Concept of next

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am learning about Data Structures(Linked List)
How does those references created for Link Class like next,first store the next link and first link respectively? in the implementation class we are just creating reference not defining anything?
How that first.next is moving? How come just creating a reference as first refers to first element in list?

```
class Link
{
public int iData; // data item (key)
public double dData; // data item
public Link next;// next link in list`


public Link(int id, double dd) // constructor
{
iData = id; // initialize data
dData = dd; // (‘next’ is automatically // set to null)
}`

`public void displayLink() // display ourself
{
System.out.print("{" + iData + ", " + dData + "} ");
}
} 
class LinkList
{
private Link first; // ref to first link on list
public LinkList() // constructor
{
first = null; // no items on list yet
}
public boolean isEmpty() // true if list is empty
{
return (first==null);`
}

// insert at start of list
public void insertFirst(int id, double dd)
{ // make new link
Link newLink = new Link(id, dd);
newLink.next = first; // newLink --> old first
first = newLink; // first --> newLink
}
public Link deleteFirst() // delete first item
{ // (assumes list not empty)
Link temp = first; // save reference to link
first = first.next; // delete it: first-->old next
return temp; // return deleted link
}


public void displayList()
{
System.out.print("List (first-->last): ");
Link current = first; // start at beginning of list
while(current != null) // until end of list,
{
current.displayLink(); // print data
current = current.next; // move to next link
}
System.out.println("");
}
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I don't understand reasons for downvote.
@Arkanon:: I just want to know how come next store link to the next element? where are we defining that?same with first.

Answer (score 0):

In a linked list, each element has a field that holds a reference to the next element, and in addition there is a variable which holds a reference to the first element in the list - the list's "head".
That way, when constructing a new `Link` element using `Link newLink = new Link(id, dd);`, its `next` field is assigned the reference to the current first element, which makes it the new first element.
Then, the list's "head" called `first` in your code is assigned a reference to the newly-created element.

Answer (score 0):

I think the part that might be confusing you is that the class is called `Link`, whereas `Node` would be a better name. Essentially, your LinkList class is linking a bunch of nodes together.

The first node that you create contains two things: some data, and a *reference* (this is what links the nodes together) to the next `Node`. The reference, which is stored in `next`, is initially set to null for every node that you make. Your `LinkList` class is updating this value every time you call the  `insertFirst(int id, double dd)` method. It creates a new `Node` with some data, and updates this node's `next` property with a reference to the node that used to be in the first position. Imagine you're creating a linked list of numbers, and you insert '10' as the first number. The list will look like this:

`'10'`

Then you call `insertFirst('9')`, and it will look like this: `'9' ----> '10'`, so the first node contains the number 9 as data, and its `next` is set to '10' by this line: `newLink.next = first; // newLink --> old first`. The node containing 9 is setting its `next` property to be the node containing 10, and then `first` is set to be the new node that you just created, which is the node containing 9. This process repeats as you continue to add nodes, so it will eventually look like `1 ----> 2 ----> 3 ----> ... ----> 8 ----> 9 ----> 10`, so each `Node` has a reference to the next node in the list.